# Gradebook, array not saving

Tags: c

So I'm trying to make a grade book that does everything displayMenu() says. But i cant even get the student ID to save when i go to view the grades. Please Help.

Everything is initialized here

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define CLS system("cls")
#define EXAMS 100
#define STUDENT 4
void displayArray(float grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]);
void newStudent(float grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]);
void displayStudentAverage(float grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]);

int main() {
float grades[STUDENT][EXAMS];
```

This is everything the program should do

```
displayMenu(grades, 0 );

} // end of main;
 int displayMenu(float grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]) {
printf("\t \t MENU \t \t");
printf("Enter Corresponding Number\n");
printf("1.Enter New Student\n");
printf("2.Change Existing Grades\n");
printf("3.View All Grades\n");
printf("4.View Average Score Per Student\n");
printf("5.View Average Score Per Exam\n");
printf("6.View Average Score For The class\n");
printf("7.CLEAR GRADEBOOK\n");
printf("8. Save Gradebook\n");
printf("8.Exit\n");
int choice = 0;
scanf("%d", &choice);
switch (choice) {
case 1:
    newStudent(grades, 0);
    CLS;
    displayMenu(grades,0);
    break;
case 2:
    break;
case 3: displayArray(grades, 0);
    CLS;
    displayMenu(grades,0);
    break;
case 4:
    displayStudentAverage(grades, 0);
    break;
case 5:
    break;
case 6:
    break;
case 7:
    break;
case 8:
    exit(0);
    break;
case 9:
    exit(0);
    break;
default: printf("You Have entered an incorrect number");
    PAUSE;
}
}
```

This is what displays the grades

```
void displayArray(float grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]) {

printf("%.1f\t", grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]);

}
```

I'm trying to add the values to the array here

```
void newStudent(float grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]) {
        float addgrade;
        printf("Please Enter Student ID: ");
        scanf("%f", &grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]);
        printf("Enter four exam grades, use comma to split grades");

        scanf("%f", addgrade);
        grades[STUDENT][EXAMS] += addgrade;

    PAUSE;
    CLS;



}

void displayStudentAverage(float grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]) {
int sum, loop;
float avg;

sum = avg = 0;

for (loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
    sum = sum + grades[loop];
}

avg = (float)sum / loop;

printf("Average of array values is %.2f", avg);

}
```

Comment: Why are you passing arguments of the array if it's a global array in the first place anyways?

Comment: I want to move the array to main but it didn't like it.

Comment: Never mind I put it in main but the array is still not saving anything I enter when I ask for the ID

Comment: So I changed it to float, or should i remove it?

Comment: I changed it to &f and now it saves, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's always good check the compiler warnings to get some hints to possible bugs...

Here's a list of problems in the code:

- no header files included
- `displayMenu` prototype is missing
- the `grades` array is used with inconsistent types (`float`/`int`)
- with `grades[STUDENT][EXAMS]` the `grades` array is accessed out of bounds (for example if you define an array of size 5 you can only access position 0 to 4)
- the return type of `main` needs to be `int`
- the function `newStudent` has return type `void` but the code tries to return something with `return &grades[STUDENT][EXAMS];`

Apart from that, the code should work...

Comment: all that makes sense and has been applied to the code. How would i got about adding new grades to that student id?

Comment: In newStudent you would have to use the student id read by scanf as the array index...

Comment: In newStudent declare a new variable `id`, scanf to that and then use `id` as the array index (`grades[id][0]`).

Comment: Would I add (`int id;`)  to initialize it?

Comment: Yes sure. That would be the declaration of `id`. To initialize `id` you would have to actually write a value to it (for example with `scanf` or the `=` operator).

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant definition instead of declaration.

Comment: also can you see why when returning to the switch statement, it defaults when i put in any number in the four exam grades.